# WMQ(IBM Queue) Connection timeout

Tags: mule, ibm-mq

I'm able connect IBM Queue directly but when u tried to connect from mule getting the below error and not able to deploy. I'm getting the below error

```
ERROR 2017-04-25 06:45:13,582    
[main]org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect:    
WebSphereMQConnector
{
 name=WMQ2
 lifecycle=initialise
this=5e7abaf7
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=false
supportedProtocols=[wmq]
serviceOverrides=<none>
}
. Root Exception was: Connection timed out: connect. Type: class    java.net.ConnectException


ERROR 2017-04-25 06:50:23,943 [main]     org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
************************************************
Message               : JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'RQACBRKB' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '172.11.11.11(6912)'.
JMS Code              : JMSWMQ0018
Element               : /WMQ2 @ app:config.xml:14 (WMQ)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)


 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9213: A communications error for  occurred [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection timed out: connect],3=rbitbrka.apl.com] at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:810) ~[?:?]
```

PFB connector details:

```
<wmq:connector name="WMQ5" hostName="${mq.host}" port="${mq.port}" queueManager="${mq.queue.manager}" channel="CLIENTS.SALES.CRM" username="${mq.user}" password="${mq.password}" transportType="CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" specification="1.1" targetClient="JMS_COMPLIANT" validateConnections="false" doc:name="WMQ" maxRedelivery="-1">
    <reconnect frequency="${mq.reconnection.period.ms}" count="${mq.reconnection.attempt}"/>
</wmq:connector>
```

When i telnet the ip and port getting below error:

```
C:\Users\111>telnet 172.11.11.11 6912
Connecting To 172.11.11.11...Could not open connection to the host, on port 6912: Connect failed
```

But when i ping getting responce

```
C:\Users\111>ping 172.11.11.11
```

Comment: What error do you see in the Queue Manager's AMQERR01.LOG?

Answer (score 1):

The pertinent pieces of information from your provided error are:-

```
JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'RQACBRKB'
with connection mode 'Client' and host name '172.11.11.11(6912)'.

com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;
```

MQRC 2538 is [MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q045380_.htm) which is explained in Knowledge Center. In there it mentions the most common reasons for this error:-

- The listener has not been started on the remote system. (please check that your listener is running on port 6912 on the machine at IP address 172.11.11.11)
- The connection name in the client channel definition is incorrect. (the connection name your client is using is '172.11.11.11(6912)' - is this correct?)
- The network is currently unavailable.
- A firewall blocking the port, or protocol-specific traffic.
- The security call initializing the IBM MQ client is blocked by a security exit on the SVRCONN channel at the server.

Answer (score 0):

"java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" usually occurs when you have a config issue or you are unable to connect to the remote server. As mentioned above do you have an error on the MQ end and if not have you checked the connection properties within config. If these are correct, are you able to reach MQ from another client, such as SOAPUI?

Can you also post the connector and flow details?